# Convert .ico to png in react native

Tags: image, react-native

So I am aware that the only supported formats in react native currently are png, jpg, jpeg, bmp, gif, webp (Android only), psd (iOS only). I was wondering if anyone knows an effective way to convert .ico images to png in react native?